# Finding the coefficient of $x^4$ of determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

> Find the coefficient of $x^4$ in the following determinant.
>
> $$\mspace{10mu}\begin{vmatrix}
> 3 & x & -1 &2  & 4\\ 
> 1 & 2x & 1 & x &1 \\ 
> -3 &2  & -1 & 1 &x \\ 
>  x& x & 4 & 5 &-2 \\ 
> 2 &-3  &x  & 4 &-5 
> \end{vmatrix}$$

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You basically have two options, as you always do when calculating a determinant: Just use the formula directly, expanding along a row or a column, or try to simplify the matrix a bit before you use the formula directly. What's stopping you?

Comment: It would have been a more interesting question if it had asked for the coefficient of $x^5$, because in the expansion there is only one such term, so you can get it directly without evaluating the determinant.

Comment: Perform elementary row operations to try to reduce to upper-triangular form. Then evaluating the determinant is trivial. This is not as difficult as you may think; for example, start by adding the third to the first row, etc.

Comment: Try expanding along the fourth row. Only two of the resulting terms can generate a term with $x^4$ in them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have found a solution. Not sure the simpliest one.

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5$ be the expending of determinant.

Then  $\mspace{10mu}f(0)=a_0=78\mspace{10mu}$  ,    $\mspace{10mu}f(1)=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5 \mspace{10mu}$  ,$\mspace{10mu}f(-1)=a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+a_4-a_5$,

$f(2)=a_0+2a_1+4a_2+8a_3+16a_4+32a_5 \mspace{10mu},$

$f(-2)=a_0-2a_1+4a_2-8a_3+16a_4-32a_5\mspace{10mu}.$

Solving the linear system

$\{f(0)=a_0 ,f(1)+f(-1)=... ,f(2)+f(-2)=...\}$

we get   $a_0,a_2,a_4.$

I hope there is more more convenient solution.